# Can I connect my dryer to the wall duct without a connector?

Tags: dryer, venting

Is it possible to attach my dryer's exhaust port directly to the vent duct without a connector? Obviously I'll need to secure the 2 together, but I'm trying to have my dryer as tight as possible to the wall. The area for my washer and dryer is just big enough for them to be side by side with a couple of inches of clearance on each side, which makes dealing with the vent work a pain.

Comment: Short vent length without turns is good, but the dryer might require extra(a few inches) clearance from the wall, so a few inches of duct might be needed

Comment: What are the relative positions of the exhaust and intake ports?

Comment: I revised your post to more clearly state what I think you're asking. Please revise further as needed. Also, flush =/= tight to. Flush means something else.

Comment: Currently the exhaust port is on the right side of the dryer (looking from the front) and the vent is on the left side approximately 2ft apart. During our remodel we will be moving the vent to match the exhaust port.